# how browser running angular 2.0 app knows whether to make a call to server or not when using "HTML 5 URLs"

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 2.0 documentation at [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles) advocates the use of "HTML 5 URLs", which basically obsoletes the use of "#" on single page apps.

Now in the old way of using #, if anything after the # changes, the browser won't make a call to server.

With the new way of using "HTML 5 URLs" how can the browser tell whether to make a call to the server or not?

My question was inspired by the following experience.

if I type in localhost:3000/login directly on the browser address bar and hit enter, the browser goes to my node server

However if i have a router.navigate['/login'] inside my angular 2.0 app it does NOT go to node server and it shows a view located on the client side. But it still shows localhost:3000/login on the browser address bar

If I then hit refresh immediately after, it tries to go to the node server again.

**Update**

The following is taken from Angular 2.0 tutorial on [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles)

> If we tell the router to navigate to the detail component and display
>   "Magneta", we expect hero id (15) to appear in the browser URL like
>   this:
>
> localhost:3000/hero/15
>
> **If a user enters that URL into the browser
>   address bar, the router should recognize the pattern and go to the
>   same "Magneta" detail view**.

I am using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser only calls to the server when you click a link or when you load a page by entering an URL into the URL bar or when you make an XMLHttpRequest from JS.

`router.navigate['/login']` is handled by the Angular2 router which has no reason to make a call to the server because that's not its purpose.
It just updates the URL shown in the URL bar using the browsers `pushState` API which doesn't cause page reloads.

Comment: Angular 2.0 documentation (look at bold sentence in the updated question) says "If a user enters that URL into the browser address bar, the router should recognize the pattern and go to the same "Magneta" detail view." I tried that in their tutorial and when I change the address bar it actually seems not to go to the server. What do you think about that? Thanks

Comment: I guess there is some additional rule in the browser about manually entered URLs if it has the same base as the previous one to not treat it as page change.

Comment: so, do you think going back to the "#" is the only way to support manually entered URLs. I have a Node server.

Comment: Uh, no. Why do you think so? Did you run into a concrete problem?

Comment: I read this else where "... you need to configure your server side to serve the index.html file **for each route you defined**." so I guess I'll have to do that. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Yea, that's a prerequisite for HTML5 pushState to work. Usually it's not "for each route you defined" but for each request to a file that actually doesn't exist. This is easier to configure than "for each route you define" which would need to be updated for any client change affecting routes.

Comment: If my user manually types www.someapp.com/login I want the **login Component** to be displayed. However if I make my server serve **index.html**, how is that going to display the login Component on the browser?

Comment: The Angular2 router kicks in and handles the additional path to display on the `index.html` what is configured in the routes config.